# Reducer and store state not in sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

Cannot work out what is going on here but basically i have a json file which has a load of products. im trying to then render the ones I want

here is my reducer:

```
export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case Types.SHOW_PRODUCTS: {
      console.log('here1');
      let productsToShow = data.filter(category => category.link === action.category)
      const newState = [].concat(productsToShow[0].products)
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      console.log('here2');
      return state;
  }
}
```

when I log the state in my store, it says that productsToRender is an array of length 5 (this is correct)

however, when I log (this.props) in one of my components, it says that the length is 0

in the above reducer, the console.log('here 1') is the last console log being called, meaning that it is definitely returning products ( that is verified in the store state). so im not sure why it is then wiping it in that component?

in that component I call this

```
  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.showProducts(this.props.chosenCategory.category)
  }
```

which passes in the chosen category so I now what products to render

however, logging this.props in the render method below, is showing it to be an empty array

of course I can post more code if necessary but any reason for this funky behaviour?

extra info:

interestingly when I do this:

```
    default:
      console.log('here2');
      return [{name: 'prod'}];
  }
```

and then log this.props, it now contains this array with this object???

Comment: Hi did you `connect` your parent component to Redux Store?

Comment: What happens if you put the call in `componentDidMount` instead?

Comment: @Winter that is what I initially had and did the same thing

Comment: @t3__rry yes i did it like so: export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);

Comment: Initially, it will be the initialState which in your case may be an empty array. When the reducer is triggered after the API call, it gets populated with data. Btw, what is the 'data' variable in your reducer?

Comment: @vijayst sure. but why is it then emptying it again? data is just my json file im pulling in. or the array of all the products

Comment: ok im very confused, i just removed everything and tried to return `<h1> Hi </h1>` and it wont render that???

Comment: ok, so now commenting out `componentWillMount' it now renders something, so for some reason that has broken the whole page??

Comment: would really appreciate any help @Winter, et al. not sure why calling the method doesn't render the component AND why it's failing in the reducer...

Comment: flip me, solved it eventually. that was fun. problem was in another reducer

Answer (score 0):

The store should be immutable, that is, the value you return should be made immutable.
I assume you are adding only a single array in the store
Try changing the reducer like,

```
const initialState = [];

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case Types.SHOW_PRODUCTS: {
      console.log('here1');
      let productsToShow = data.filter(category => category.link === action.category)
      let newState = [...state,...productsToShow[0].products]
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      console.log('here2');
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, did you try this method??